# Map not show after project compiled

Tags: java, android

Hi I try to create a simple Map project in Eclipse, when I run my project from Eclipse to device, my map can shown, but when my project was compiled as `.apk` my map not shown in my Fragment. How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you signed your APK with a different keystore you may not have registered both your debug and release keystore on the Google Developer Console.

Check out this link for details on how to add both SHA1 fingerprints (debug and release) so that your API Key works on both.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key